# How do I execute multiple AND operators and OR operators using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

The first query works and displays the proper results.  When I add an additional AND condition I get a "Trying to get property of a non-object" error.

I can successfully execute with one OR and one other condition.

Here is the query echoed:

```
SELECT * FROM scores 
WHERE (sortDate <= 20190629 AND sport = football) 
       AND (homeID = 4 OR awayID = 4) 
ORDER BY gameDate DESC
```

I'm sure the variable are passing through.

This one works fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores 
WHERE sortDate <= $today
AND (homeID = $teamID OR awayID = $teamID)
ORDER BY gameDate DESC";
```

This one gives an error (added AND):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores 
WHERE (sortDate <= $today AND sport = $sportID)
AND (homeID = $teamID OR awayID = $teamID)
ORDER BY gameDate DESC";
```

Comment: `sport` is a string. You should do: `AND sport = '$sportID'`

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores 
WHERE sortDate <= $today AND sport = $sportID
AND (homeID = $teamID OR awayID = $teamID)
ORDER BY gameDate DESC";

Comment: That worked!!  Thank you very much.  Could you tell me what you mean by "sport is string"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores 
WHERE (sortDate <= $today AND sport = '$sportID')
AND (homeID = $teamID OR awayID = $teamID)
ORDER BY gameDate DESC";
```

**OR**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores 
WHERE (sortDate <= $today) AND (sport = $sportID)
AND (homeID = $teamID OR awayID = $teamID)
ORDER BY gameDate DESC";
```

Comment: The first one worked with the single quotes (THANK YOU!).  Why did it work?  None of the others have single quotes.  It was said that "sport is a string"  what does that mean?

Comment: It works for you fine. click the answer. It works because $sportID is the string (set of characters)  as you tell it like football.

Comment: It is much better to use prepared statements. All the problems with quotes are then gone.